# android: simulator identical to product of perticular companies

Tags: android, device

I am using the default simulator, Can I make simulator identical to some common device
I mean one identical to HTC, one identical to droid motorla, one of samsung, dell, acer,..etc
Here identical I mean all the features that it provide.
Thanks

Comment: Android comes with a default stimulator? Sounds ... interesting. Does it use the phone's vibration function or is it something more complex?

Comment: @Ranieri: It's a new Google technique. Stimulation is good for developers. har har. ;)

Comment: haha very funny guys. @Labeeb-P it's "Simulator", not "Stimulator".

Comment: haha....i'm sorry and thanks @KevinDTimm editing it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes labbeb Brother, you can download the various devices skin as Htc, samsung and mortolo droid from the following url

```
http://teavuihuang.com/android/
```

and unzip the skin which is downloaded and put in the  android sdk directory/platform/android3/skins.

Like that do the same for android4,7,8 too

Answer (score 0):

These different devices can be determined by the sets of capabilities that they have as well as which version operating system they support. That's what the "Android SDK and AVD Manager" is for. When you create a new device in the manager, you can select the target API version, screen resolution, and hardware supported in order to emulate a certain type of phone.

For instance, if I was developing on an HTC Hero I would want to ensure that I specify the target API as Android 2.1-update1 - API Level 7 since it is the highest that the Hero supports without a custom ROM at the moment.

Another example is the upcoming Motorola i886. It is an Android OS phone that does not have a touch screen, so for it's hardware you would add the property "Touch Screen Support" = "No".

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, a simulator is just that -- it can't provide full and true emulation of the target hardware. To get all features, nuances, bugs, skins, add-ons, pre-installed apps, and whatnot that the target hardware comes with you must acquire the target hardware. There's no full-proof alternative to this yet.

You can, however, simulate many of the important characteristics of the target device. Tilsan linked to a good resource for downloading a whole bunch of skins. You can create your own, too (see
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/common-android-virtual-device-configurations/).

Answer (score 0):

The default or generic simulator is to display the general functions and may not be  specific to any present or future model in the final form. Only authorised developers, manufacturers and industry organisations like OHA the open handset alliance are permitted to develop for specific models as some of the internal hardware including the processor may be proprietory or patented for use in specific countries and open access to the internals could be a breach of rights protection. When using API and APP type environments as application programmers and hobbyists then the development kit can be specific to models and is provided by the brand name or manufacturer by download or on CD and is a concession to the user community.